# Adding OKTA user to a group in C# using api

Tags: c#, api, okta

I was able to add a user but now I need to add that user to an Okta group.  I am doing this in C# and was using the following code:

```
 var oktaClient = new OktaClient("apitoken", new Uri("https<domain>.okta.com"));
var groupClient = oktaClient.GetGroupsClient();
var groupName = groupClient.GetByName("<group_name>");
var usersClient = oktaClient.GetUsersClient();
var groupUsersClient = new GroupUsersClient(   groupName, "<apitoken>", "<subdomain>");
var user = new User("<emailaddress>", "<Emailaddress>", "<firstname>", "<lastname>");
var user1 = usersClient.Add(user);
groupUsersClient.Add(user1);
```

This gives me an error on groupUsersClient.Add(user1) of Error Code E0000006-You do not have permission to perform the requested action ErrorId = oaecyuJZZguQ1OkuLLook58wQ

Am I not using the right api calls or is there something else I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the API token that you are using in your code has right privileges? API token has same permissions as the admin user who created that API token.

Please see this article https://support.okta.com/help/articles/Knowledge_Article/99850906-Administrator-Role. It seems like the API token was created using the account with User admin level or lower access.

Create an API token with org or super admin account and try again.